# Firebase stripe extension month to annual subscription

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments

I have created a reactjs application connected to firebase and uses firebase stripe extension. i have followed the documentation and successfully implemented subscription.

I have a scenario wherein user can upgrade to monthly to anual subscription.
How can i implement this?
And what would be the best way to implement it.
here is my current code.

`import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';  const stripe = await loadStripe("pk_test_productkey"); stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId })`

I have created 2 product in stripe, 1 monthly recurring and 1 annual recurring. If i am already subscribe to monthly subscription, it does not allow me to subscribe to annual subscription.

And what would be the best way to implement it.

Comment: Upgrading or downgrading can be done with Customer Portal with [`createPortalLink`](https://github.com/invertase/stripe-firebase-extensions/tree/next/firestore-stripe-payments) function.